# passing grid view data between forms in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio

I have two forms.

Form #1 has person detail: Name, phone, country, etc.

Form #2 has a grid view showing a list of persons.

How can I pass a data row from the grid view in form #2 to form #1's controls when the row is double-clicked?

Comment: Don't try to pass the row between the grids, instead, pass the relevant data from the first form to the second one. there are multiple ways of doing this - use the constructor of the second form, or a custom property on it, or a method. a form is simply an object, so it's just like passing data from `foo` to `bar`.

Comment: Can you write the code plz

Answer (score 4):

Please follow these steps.

1. Create a class (clsGlobal in my demo) and declare two public static references to both Form1 and Form2

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace Stack1
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// These references are now can be accessed any where within the    solution.
   /// </summary>
       public class clsGlobal
       {
           public static  Form1 frm1;
           public static Form2 frm2;
       }
   }
   ```

[image: clsGlobal.cs]

2. Then Edit the Program.cs if this Form1 is your Starting Form. If not no need. You may can do this to your Starting Form if you ever want. I'm doing this because my starting Form is Form1 in my demo.

   ```
   static class Program
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// The main entry point for the application.
       /// </summary>
       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

           //Use the global reference for form1
           clsGlobal.frm1 = new Form1();
           Application.Run(clsGlobal.frm1);
       }
   }
   ```

[image: Program.cs]

3. Then Design the Form1 and Form2. In Form1 make all the Modifier of all the TextBoxes Private to Public to make them accessible to other classes (Here Form2). To do that go to Properties of the TextBox and then change to value of the Modifiers property to Public

[image: Form1 Design]

4. In Form2 select the DataGridView and then go to its Properties -> Events and select the "RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick" event from the list of events.

[image: Form2 Design]

5. In here to add the data into my DataGrid in my Demo I created a DataTable manually and set it as the DataSource of the DataGrid but you can skip this step because you already have the data in the DataGridView.

   ```
   public Form2()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       //You may don't need to do this part. You may can fetch the data from the database
       /////////////////////// To Disaplay Data On the DataGrid /////////////////
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       dt.Columns.Add("Name");
       dt.Columns.Add("Phone");
       dt.Columns.Add("Country");

       dt.Rows.Add("Supun", "+940711288825", "Sri Lanka");
       dt.Rows.Add("Nimantha", "+940783193677", "Sri Lanka");

       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       // To avoid select multiple rows at once
       dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;

   }
   ```
6. Complete the "RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick" event of Form2

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   {
       //We know surely if this event fired there will be one selected row for sure
       //It is in the 0th index in the collection of SelectedRows

       //To access these textbox controls of form 1 inside form 2 you have to set 
       //their Modifiers to Public
       // We use the same instance of the form1 which is already opened

        clsGlobal.frm1.txtName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        clsGlobal.frm1.txtPhone.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        clsGlobal.frm1.txtCountry.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

       //clsoe the Form2
        this.Close();
   }
   ```

[image: Form2.cs]

7. In Form1 in the click Event of  the appropriate button (In Demo btnOpenGridForm) do as follow

   ```
   private void btnOpenGridForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Use global reference for Form2
       clsGlobal.frm2 = new Form2();
       //You can't access Form1 now. if you want use .Show() instead of .ShowDialog()
       clsGlobal.frm2.ShowDialog();
   }
   ```

[image: Form1.cs]

8. This solution is tested and worked for me but we may can have alternative solutions for this.

[image: Before RowHeader Double Click]

[image: After RowHeader Double Click]